# rails: how to store and access data locally to a particular request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to have a local object that i initialize at the beginning of each request. the thread processing that request is the only one able to access or modify that object during the request. at the end of the request, the local object can be  cleared or destroyed. is the canonical way to do this by attaching some data to the request or the session? alternatively, what about Thread.local? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your exact requirements are unclear.

So far it sounds like an[`around_filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters) and an instance variable would be sufficient. If you have no specific cleanup requests, you'd only need a `before_filter`.

Comment: a requirement is that there is an object persistant across requests that would be accessing this variable. an instance variable seems like it would not be only accessed by one thread due to multiple workers running simultaneously. if you used an instance variable, where would it be attached and how would it be accessed?

Comment: @HeinrichSchmetterling You said the thread accessing the object is the only one able to access or modify the object during the request, and at the end of the request the object can be destroyed. You also didn't say anything about "multiple workers". I don't know what you're asking for.